# implement a list with a static method javascript

Tags: javascript, list, implementation

I must reimplement a list and the method forEach with the following instructions:

// Do *not* construct any array literal ([]) in your solution.

// Do *not* construct any arrays through new Array in your solution.

// DO *not* use any of the Array.prototype methods in your solution.

// You may use the destructuring and spreading (...) syntax from Iterable.

the result should look like:

```
const list = List.create(1, 2)
list.forEach((item) => console.log(item))
```

Here is my incomplete solution:

```
export class List {

  constuctor(){
    
  }

  public static create(...values: number[]): List {
    // Do *not* construct any array literal ([]) in your solution.
    // Do *not* construct any arrays through new Array in your solution.
    // DO *not* use any of the Array.prototype methods in your solution.

        // You may use the destructuring and spreading (...) syntax from Iterable.
        List list = new List();
        values.forEach(function(item){
          list.push(item);
        });  
        return list;
      }
    
      public forEach(callback: any){
        for (let i = 0; i<this.length ; i++){
           callback(this[i], i, this);
        }
      }
    
    }
```

in the create loop, but the problem, as a static method, the this is not recognized

**EDITED thanks to comments**

Comment: And what is your problem to use a variable holding the created `List` instead of using `this`?.

Comment: my problem is to populate first the create method so that const list = List.create(1, 2) works

Comment: Ok, but what is your problem to create an instance of `List` within the `create` method, use that instead of `this` and return it from `create`?

Comment: yes, but how to create an instance of List within the create method ?

Comment: The same way as anywhere else: by using `new`.

Comment: yes, but a condition is that: Do not construct any arrays through new Array in your solution.

Comment: Yes, you have to create a List and not an Array.

Comment: I have updated my answer but I get still an error

Comment: it does not work because your `List` class does not have a `push` function. You need to implement that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...`this` is not recognised

It is. But you have not given `this` any property. And this is because:

- `constuctor` should be written as `constructor`
- You need to define a `push` method (since you call it in `create`)
- You need to define a `length` property (since you reference it in `forEach`)

Furthermore, there some other issues:

- you write that `Array.prototype` functions cannot be used, but your code has `values.forEach()`, ... so that is a violation of that rule. Use a `for..of` loop instead.

Here is your code with those remarks taken on board:

```js
class List {
  constructor() {
    this.length = 0;    
  }

  push(value) {
    this[this.length++] = value;
  }

  static create(...values) {
    let list = new List();
    for (let item of values) {
      list.push(item);
    }
    return list;
  }
    
  forEach(callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length ; i++) {
      callback(this[i], i, this);
    }
  }
}


const list = List.create(1, 2)
list.forEach((item) => console.log(item))
```

### Remarks

The above "test" will be fine, but when also assignments to properties are to work correctly, like `list[2] = 3`, then there are more things to take care of. Take for instance this program:

```
const list = List.create(1, 2);
list[5] = 42; // should update length
list.check = true; // should not update length
console.log("length = " + list.length);
console.log("enumerable keys are " + Object.keys(list));
list.forEach((item) => console.log(item)); // should not output empty slots
list.length = 1; // should delete some index properties
list.forEach((item) => console.log(item)); // should not output deleted items
```

...then the output should be:

```
length = 6
enumerable keys are 0,1,5,check
1
2
42
1
```

You can make this happen by trapping the access to properties, and making  `length` a getter/setter. But you'd also need to distinguish between properties that are *array indices*, and which are not, so all-in-all that would make the code less trivial.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution and the complementary remarks !