# Implement a list with a static method in JavaScript (TypeScript flavour)

Tags: typescript, list

This is the same as
[implement a list with a static method javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71218676/implement-a-list-with-a-static-method-javascript) but with the TypeScript flavour

```typescript
export class List {

  length: number;

  constructor(){
    this.length = 0;
  }

  public static create(...values: number[]): List {

    let list = new List();
    values.forEach(function(item){
      list.push(item);
    });  
    return list;
  }

  public forEach(callback: (n: any, index?: number, list?: List) => void): void {
    let i:number;
    for (i = 0; i<this.length ; i++){
       callback(this[i], i, this); // line 34
    }
  }

  push(value: number): void {
    this[this.length++] = value; // line 39
  }
```

Could you help me debug ?

> list-ops.ts(34,17): error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'List'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'List'.
> list-ops.ts(39,5): error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'List'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'List'.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to limit yourself to the same cryptic handcuffs the original did? (the "Do not" comments)? Also, is there a reason you pulled the code from the question, rather than the answer?

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey, I have deleted the cryptic handcuffs if you find disturbing. However, I have pulled the code from the anwser (which was in javascript) and tried to convert it in typescript (in the original question , there was no push implementation  and the constructor was void for example)

Comment: Well, what's the purpose of this?  Why not just inherit from `Array` and add the `create` method (I'd use `from` or `map` myself).

Comment: Hi, the aim is to reimplement the different methods for a list (such as map, push), that's why I need first to create the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error about getting and setting arbitrary properties `list[i]` because those properties have not been defined and TypeScript doesn't know about them:

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'List'.

The solution is very simple -- you just need to add an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) to your class.

```
export class List {

    [i: number]: number;

    length: number;

    constructor() {
...
```

This says that any `number` is a valid property of your `List` object and that the value of that property will be a `number`.